# Working with netTcpBinding in Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, nettcpbinding

I Have created a WCF service that hosted in IIS 7

My .NET version is 4.0

My Operating System is Windows 7 Ultimate

My Service Address:

- net.tcp://localhost:4504/WPFHost/tcp

When i added service reference i get two warning:

First:

```
Warning 2   Custom tool warning: Endpoint 'NetTcpBinding_IChat' at address 'net.tcp://localhost:4504/WPFHost/tcp' is not compatible with Silverlight 4. Skipping... D:\Projects\C#\WCF\SilverlightApplication1\SilverlightApplication1\Service References\SV\Reference.svcmap   1   1   SilverlightApplication1
```

Second:

```
Warning 3   Custom tool warning: No endpoints compatible with Silverlight 4 were found. The generated client class will not be usable unless endpoint information is provided via the constructor.  D:\Projects\C#\WCF\SilverlightApplication1\SilverlightApplication1\Service References\SV\Reference.svcmap   1   1   SilverlightApplication1
```

My service Appconfig file is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFService.Service"
                     behaviorConfiguration="behaviorConfig">

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:4504/WPFHost/"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4505/WPFHost/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="tcp"
                          binding="netTcpBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                          contract="WCFChatLibrary.IChat"/>

        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:4503/WPFHost/mex"
                          binding="mexTcpBinding"
                          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behaviorConfig">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpBinding"
                         maxBufferSize="67108864"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
                         maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                         transferMode="Buffered"
                         closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                         openTimeout="00:00:10"
                         receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                         sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                         maxConnections="100">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864"
                                  maxBytesPerRead="67108864"
                                  maxStringContentLength="67108864"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When i call the service it throw exception. Here is my code:

```
if (this.proxy == null)
        {
            try
            {
                this.StatusTxtBlock.Text = "Ready";
                this.localClient = new Client();
                this.localClient.Username = "User-" + Guid.NewGuid();
                this.proxy = new ChatClient(new InstanceContext(this));

                this.proxy.OpenAsync();
                this.proxy.ConnectAsync(this.localClient);
                this.proxy.ConnectCompleted += new EventHandler<ConnectCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_ConnectCompleted);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.StatusTxtBlock.Text = "Exception: "+ ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

and the exception is:

```
Exception: The given key was not present in the dictionary
```

I follow this [tutorial](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/11/wcf-nettcp-protocol-in-silverlight-4.html) but no luck

I don't know what to do, my mind and vision is going to blank, maybe i'm going crazy. Please somebody save me (i mean help me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight 4 supports a subset of `NetTcpBinding` on the server. It doesn't support security, for example (which is fine for your case, since you have `<security mode="None">` in your binding), and it also doesn't support reliable messaging (which is likely the problem in your case, since you have it enabled in your binding). This is one binding configuration for `netTcpBinding` which is compatible with SL:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="SLCompatible">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: it doesn't work in manual WCF service, but when i tried to build WCF under Silverlight project and use your solution it work, thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896571%28VS.95%29.aspx) states that `NetTcpBinding` cannot be used with Silverlight 4.

I'm not sure whether to believe Tomasz Janczuk or MSDN, but Tomasz's article is 2 years old, so my guess is: `NetTcpBinding` was planned for Silverlight 4 but not included in the end.

You can consider switching to `BasicHttpBinding` or 'roll your own' custom binding as described in the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347793%28VS.100%29.aspx).